# Click on page from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How can a chrome extension click on a button on active page?

There is banal page on the Web. There is simple element of button type with specific ID on the page. Also there is Chrome extension with a button. I'd like to click to extension button and the button in turn clicks to page button.

```
var someElement = document.getElementById('someElement');
someElement.addEventListener('click', function () {
  // here I'd like to click on a button with specific ID.
});
```

Comment: "This question body does not meet our quality standards." There is zero effort demonstrated, both in solving and searching for a solution. Take a moment to look through [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Xan, I've tried to find something, but useless. I'd like to know only how to click on button. But SOF forces me to write more than I want. And I wrote SOF's comment.

Comment: Tell us what you know already. Tell you what you think the structure of the extension should be. We will not write a whole extension for you, show us which part needs help.

Comment: We can't read your mind but apparently you need [tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) to inject something like `document.getElementById('someElement').click()`, see [Page Redder sample extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:executescript). And take a look at the most popular questions to see the examples of properly stated questions.

Comment: It's not that hard to write a much better question, is it? Now you have a bit of code that you think is relevant, and that shows how much you understand already; also, now the problem is better specified (what should trigger the action and what should happen).

Answer (score 6):

The very first thing you want to do is to read the [Overview page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview), **especially** the [Architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) part. Read it thoroughly, and it will answer many questions you have.

Your problem can be split into two parts.

1. How to trigger something with a click on your extension.
2. How to click something inside the active tab.

Before I proceed, I'll reiterate what wOxxOm said: there's [a great small example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:page%20redder) in the docs that does nearly what you want. But if you want to be someone taught to fish, not given a fish, read on.

### How to trigger something with a click on your extension

It depends on what kind of UI you're using; the simplest is a [Browser Action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) button.

**Simplest button:**

If you add a browser action to the manifest *without* specifying a popup:

```
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": { "38": "icon38.png" }
},
```

then clicking on it will raise `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` event to your extension's pages. The only page open at any time you need it is a [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages), the role of which is usually the central dispatch for extension events. So, you need a background page that listens to that event:

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
```

and

```
// background.js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // Okay, the actual action should go here
  // And look, we already have the required Tab object for free!
});
```

**Variations (exercises for the reader):**

- If you do specify a `"default_popup"` in your manifest, then `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` will not trigger. Instead, [a small popup page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#popups) will open with the HTML file you specify; you can add UI/logic there as you wish, the principle will be the same as normal webpages but with Chrome API access, except:

  - You'll need to [query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) for the current tab yourself.
  - You'll need to be mindful of [Chrome's extension CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution).
  - In case you run into problems, you need to know [how to debug them](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging).
- If your extension targets only a few specific pages, consider using Page Actions instead of Browser Actions.
- As noted in the documentation, [Event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) are preferable to Background pages. In this case, you can use an Event page easily without any side effects, but in general this [may require some thinking](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#transition).
- You could inject your own UI into the page itself with [Content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts); this is an advanced topic and will not be covered here.

### How to click something inside the active tab

Since you've read the [Architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch), you already know that the only part of the extension that can interact with the DOM of an open page is a [Content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Content scripts can either be [specified in the manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration) (and then they will automatically be injected and ready for you when a matching page is opened), or they can be [manually injected](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) into the page.

In your case, you want to do something simple, and only when clicked. This is a perfect job for programmatic injection, so we'll stick with that.

Assuming the solution from the previous section, you are in a context of a background page and already have the current tab as the `tab` variable:

```
// background.js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // Do something with tab
});
```

Programmatic injection is done with [`chrome.tabs.executeScript` method](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript). At a minimum, you need to specify the tab you want to inject to, and the code that will be run:

```
// background.js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    code: "document.getElementById('#specificId').click()"
  });
});
```

That's not all *yet* though. The extension must have [permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) to execute code in an open tab.

You could use "host permissions" that are defined by a [match pattern](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) to give access to specific pages, but remember that we are only triggering it when the user clicks the extension.

For that specific case, there's a special permission [`"activeTab"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab). It is sufficient to do a lot of things with the currently active tab when the extension is *explicitly invoked*, and clicking its button is explicit enough.

So, add to manifest:

```
"permissions": ["activeTab"],
```

And that should be all you need for this to work.

**Extra credit:**

- While not necessary for this simple purpose, you may want more complicated code than a single line to be executed in the tab. Then it makes sense to use a separate file and [invoke `executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) with `"file"` instead of `"code"`.
- Just triggering a click on a button does not require you to directly interact with JavaScript running in the page itself, as DOM events are shared. However, it's important to understand that normally, content scripts [can't interact with the page's own scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment), which is called "isolated world". There are ways to bypass it if you really need it, but it's an advanced topic [better explained elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script).
- Sometimes you need the content script to persist, answer some commands and maybe send its own queries to the extension's pages. In that case, it's probably better to auto-inject through the manifest and use [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) instead of `executeScript`.